# Is it bad to have a CHEF wrapper cookbook for every environment?

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to chef, and I'm trying to setup cookbooks for my infrastructure.

I have several types of web servers. I have the base webserver cookbook, and I have 3 wrapper cookbooks. One for each type of web server.

base

- web

wrappers

- web_mail
- web_scheduled
- web_hsm

I want to setup multiple environments so that QA and Production servers can point to different databases. (Using variables in .erb templates).  I also want to use cookbook version promotion to ensure each version is tested in stage before production.

- Production
- Stage
- QA
- Dev

While I could simply put the database variables in the environment attributes, or in roles, [this blog,](http://dougireton.com/blog/2013/02/16/chef-cookbook-anti-patterns/) suggests that that is an anti pattern and it is better to use environment wrapper cookbooks.

However, If I use environment wrapper cookbooks, I will have an unmanageable 4x3 matrix of cookbooks (13 cookbooks total).

Is there another way to combine wrapper cookbooks, with multiple environments?